# How do I limit column span to available columns in CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to create a grid with fixed column and row sizes, which contains items that can either span 1, 2, 3 or 4 columns (and 1 or 2 rows).

This is fine as long as the `.grid` is wide enough to fit at least as many columns as the largest item, e.g the `.grid` is 600px + gap, and there's an item that spans 2 columns.

However, when the grid gets smaller, the `grid-column: span <more than available columns>` the column just collapses (See snippet below for demo).

**Question:** Is there a way to say that an item "should span X columns if possible, otherwise X-1 columns"? So a "triple" item in my example would instead only cover 2 columns, if that's what's available.

If not, is there another prefered way of approaching this problem?

**NOTE:** I know I can solve this with some JavaScript and set the column span for the different items based on the container size, e.g using a `ResizeObserver`. But I'd really prefer a CSS-only solution to this.

Also, media queries is not an option since the grid will be sized based on other constraints rather than just the viewport size.

```js
function smallGrid() {
  document.querySelector(".grid").style.width = "300px";
}

function largeGrid() {
  document.querySelector(".grid").style.width = "440px";
}
```

```css
.grid {
  --size: 100px;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, var(--size));
  grid-auto-rows: var(--size);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px lightgray;
}

.item.double {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item.triple {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.item.quad {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid" style="width: 440px">
  <article class="triple item">3x1</article>
  <article class="item">1x1</article>
  <article class="item">1x1</article>
  <article class="double item">2x1</article>
  <article class="item">1x1</article>
  <article class="quad item">4x1</article>
</section>
<section>
  <button onclick="largeGrid()">Large Grid</button>
  <button onclick="smallGrid()">Small Grid</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067750/css-responsive-grid-layout-grid-column-span-breaking-minmax) which is basically the same as mine. It's been around for 3 years and so far the best answer seems to be "not possible without media queries", which translates to "not possible without js (or container queries)" for me.

Answer (score -1):

you can span it to the end with the help of negative indexes

```
grid-column: 1/-1;
```